# How to make my app use 4.x style while customer's android phone is 4.x?

Tags: android, user-interface

How to make my app use 4.x style while customer's android phone is 4.x?
I know set android:minSdkVersion="15", the style will be 4.x. But I want the app should be compatible for android 2.0 or above.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Set your theme as Theme.DeviceDefault or define your theme styles.xml under values-11 and values folders.

Be carefull that use lint to check if you use the NewAPI with version check.